# Java/JUnit testing: test compiles, but get 'cannot find symbol' error on test Class at runtime

Tags: java, junit

I'm new to formal unit testing, so I'm trying to learn JUnit to get some practice. I have an existing project that runs, but am just now writing a unit test (for practice sake).

I'm working in Netbeans 11.3, which has Junit 4 and 5 out of the box. Netbeans allows me to right click my source packages folder > New > Test for existing class. Completing the 'wizard' yields a skeleton of the test cases that are needed for my desired class "DBUtils"(from the source package).

Netbeans places this new DBUtilsTest.java in a test packages folder of its own, but is still in the package 'scheduler', which is where the original source class DBUtils is as well.

[image]

Here is the test code:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package scheduler;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Dave
 */
public class DBUtilsTest {
    
    public DBUtilsTest() {
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of closeDBConnection method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testCloseDBConnection() {
        System.out.println("closeDBConnection");
        DBUtils.closeDBConnection();
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of openDB method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testOpenDB() {
        System.out.println("openDB");
        String connString = "";
        String user = "";
        String password = "";
        DBUtils.openDB(connString, user, password);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of addAutoIncrement method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testAddAutoIncrement() {
        System.out.println("addAutoIncrement");
        DBUtils.addAutoIncrement();
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of insertCountry method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testInsertCountry() {
        System.out.println("insertCountry");
        String country = "";
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = DBUtils.insertCountry(country);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of insertCity method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testInsertCity() {
        System.out.println("insertCity");
        String city = "";
        int countryId = 0;
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = DBUtils.insertCity(city, countryId);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of insertAddress method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testInsertAddress() {
        System.out.println("insertAddress");
        String address = "";
        String address2 = "";
        int cityId = 0;
        String postalCode = "";
        String phone = "";
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = DBUtils.insertAddress(address, address2, cityId, postalCode, phone);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of insertCustomer method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testInsertCustomer() {
        System.out.println("insertCustomer");
        String customerName = "";
        int addressId = 0;
        boolean active = false;
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = DBUtils.insertCustomer(customerName, addressId, active);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of insertAppointment method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testInsertAppointment() {
        System.out.println("insertAppointment");
        int customerId = 0;
        int userId = 0;
        String title = "";
        String description = "";
        String location = "";
        String contact = "";
        String type = "";
        String url = "";
        LocalDateTime start = null;
        LocalDateTime end = null;
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = DBUtils.insertAppointment(customerId, userId, title, description, location, contact, type, url, start, end);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of insertUser method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testInsertUser() {
        System.out.println("insertUser");
        String userName = "";
        String password = "";
        Boolean active = null;
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = DBUtils.insertUser(userName, password, active);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of deleteItem method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDeleteItem() {
        System.out.println("deleteItem");
        String table = "";
        int id = 0;
        DBUtils.deleteItem(table, id);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of updateItem method, of class DBUtils.
     */
    @Test
    public void testUpdateItem() {
        System.out.println("updateItem");
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int nextIndex = 0;
        DBUtils.updateItem(stmt, nextIndex);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
    
}
```

The details of the test aren't important yet, and the DBUtilsTest.java file compiles. However, when I go to run the test, I get a bunch of these:

```
C:\Users\Dave\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Scheduler\test\scheduler\DBUtilsTest.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
        DBUtils.closeDBConnection();
  symbol:   variable DBUtils
  location: class DBUtilsTest
```

I would think since DBUtilsTest has access to the 'scheduler' package, it should find DBUtils just fine. I'm also wondering why when I explicitly compile the DBUtilsTest.java file, these compiler-ish errors don't appear... only when I try to run it.

Any ideas on this? I've searched a little online, but haven't been able to find this answered, only asked.

Comment: Maybe it is getting confused because you have two packages with the same name.  Try to rename one.

Comment: @ScaryWombat the package name was autogenerated. I don't believe this is an issue. Its actually the same package, just a different folder.